# Edit list of pictures that has foreign key to model

Tags: python, django

I have the following two models:

```
class Profile(AbstractUser, CommonInfo):
    ...
    pictures = models.ManyToManyField(Picture, blank=True)
```

and

```
class Picture(CommonInfo):
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery/', blank=True, null=True)
```

What is the best way to display those pictures in a custom template/form/view.

I want to display them all and to delete several of them and add new.

Comment: what do you mean by "best way"?

Comment: Well, I don't have a clue how to do it, so any way will be the best way :D

Comment: SO is not code a free coding service, nor a tutorial website. I would recommend you to go over some Django tutorials, try to solve the problem by yourself and when you get stuck, or have an issue then post a question with a legit example, and exact problem. Thanks

Comment: I tried to search for solution for that and have tried some stuff, but I still have no clue. This is why I decided to ask question to see it clear.

Comment: [Tango with Django](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/) is a nice tutorial that will get you started with django. Its free, and has good explanations. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Set media url and root in settings.py

   ```
   MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
   MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
   ```
2. Make changes in urls.py of the project

   ```
   urlpatterns = [
    url(...)
    url(...)
   ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
   ```

Now you will be able to access the media files in template and perform different operations.